# Mplayer only flushing every 256k

Tags: ffmpeg, cache, mplayer

I am recording audio in a script in order to play it back later with a time shift.

The script regularly checks if the stream is still active. Sometimes live radio streams get interrupted. In that case I want to restart the recording in a new dump file.

Actual recording is done with mplayer:

```
/usr/bin/mplayer -novideo -dumpaudio      http://194.232.200.147:8000 -dumpfile orf_salzburg_1566868130-1566868130.mp3
```

I check whether the stream is still active by checking the file size periodically. When it does not increase anymore, I restart the recording.

That worked fine on an older Debian machine, using this mplayer version:

```
MPlayer svn r34540 (Debian), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
```

Now as it happens I am developing on a new machine, using this version:

```
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-6.2.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
```

The old version writes the file instantly. When I query the written file every 100ms I see the file size increasing every 100ms.

However, using the new mplayer version, the file is written in chunks of 256kbyte. That can take up to 16 seconds before the file size increase is visible.

Strangely enough, even the new mplayer reports in the command line an continuously number of bytes being written. But in reality it is only in chunks op 256k.

I believe this behaviour is due to using the ffmpeg lib in mplayer. Ffmpeg flushes every 256kbyte. But there is an option in ffmpeg to flush the output. It is not in mplayer as it seems.

It is easy enough to change the period in my script to check the file size growth. But, when I change it to 20-30 seconds, I loose a lot of audio when the stream in interrupted.

Any suggestions as how to revert mplayer to its old behaviour?

Comment: Why not use ffmpeg? If you can't, can you pipe to ffmpeg and set -flush_packets 1.

Comment: @Gyan: I did not use ffmpeg because I did not know it could be used like that. But ffmpeg can also record streams, and it works perfectly. It even does not buffer until 256kB, it writes continuously. The only strange this is that the stream is 160k. At playback 128k is reported. Playing a file which was recorded with mplayer, the reported bitrate is 192k. But when I calculate the file size, it is 170k for both recorders. Also ffmpeg says it records at 4x speed, dropping to 1 after some minutes. But the recording seems to be time-accurate

Comment: Time accuracy is a requirement for my application as I need to shift exactly 6 hours in time. The correct (or at least the working) command line for ffmpeg is ffmpeg  -i http://194.232.200.147:8000  Orf_salzburg_1566868130-1566868130.mp3. If you post this I can mark it as solution.